# Get SharePoint Site Collection Structure to JSON

Tags: 2013

I would like to get information like below,

```
SiteCollection
--- RootSite
------Site1
------------Site1.1
--------------------List1
------------Site1.2
------------Site1.3
------Site2
------Site3
------Site4
```

I want to get this information as a JSON, I know I can get it as a csv using following PS code,

```
$allwebapps = Get-SPWebApplication | select url foreach ($webapp in $allwebapps) {
    Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select Title, URL, ID, ParentWebID | Export-CSV “C:\Users\A\Desktop\Structure.csv”
-NoTypeInformation }
```

I am not sure if there's anything out there already or I can change this script

Answer (score 1):

If you update your PowerShell version to 5, you will be able to use the standard Cmdlet `ConvertTo-Json`

[Official Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is that you get the complete site Structure using PNP Powershell and later convert this *well-formed Site Template XML to JSON*

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out template.pnp -Handlers Lists, SiteSecurity
```

You can omit the handlers if you want the default site template xml.

[Read More..](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps)